# gksudo doesn't act like sudo for 'string' >> file

Tags: command-line, scripts, gksudo

I'm trying to do a two-lines-script to temporary set a specific nameserver. Therefore I just output `'nameserver XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'` to the `/etc/resolv.conf` file, because it gets overwritten next time anyways. The thing is, when I try to ask for the password via gksudo, I get an error because it tries to output the gksudo result to the file.

UPDATE:

My current file is now:

```
#!/bin/sh
gksudo "bash -c \"echo 'nameserver XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' >> /etc/resolv.conf\""
```

The command with `sudo` instead of `gksudo` and without the `""` and `\\` works as it should. Remains how to get it into the GUI prompt.

Answer (score 3):

You were very close, try that:

```
#!/bin/sh
gksudo "bash -c \"echo 'nameserver XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' >> /etc/resolv.conf\""
```

Comment: Unfortunately, gksudo takes the `-c` now as one of its options. :-/

Comment: @PeterNerlich I edited the answer, please try again

Comment: Well, it does now kind of what it should, it only somehow fails without returning an error... It works with `sudo` and without the "" and \\ all around, but `gksudo` won't. Strange...

Answer (score 1):

As you can read here -
http://sernaonubuntu.wikidot.com/command-line:piping-and-directing-output the >> symbol appends the result of the command to the file

The result of `'nameserver XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'` command is.. well command not found :P

What comes to the rescue is the echo command (as @chaos rightfully said) which echoes the text and that result can be piped to the file

Though you can use a simpler version of his script

```
#!/bin/sh
gksudo echo 'nameserver XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

Answer (score -4):

Have you tryed this in sted type in this:

```
    #!bin/sh
           Case (nameserver) in
                 /bin/sh
                 nameserver = XXX.XXX.XXX XXX >>
                 gksudo 'echo' nameserver >>
                 resolvconf XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX >>
           endl
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Which syntax is this? Surely not any shell?

Comment: @Rmano same language as [this one](http://askubuntu.com/a/537715/158442).